# Cannot assign a value of type '[(String)]' to a value of type 'String!'?

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, textview

`woodText.text = [String](textForWood.values)` This is my code. `woodText` is a `UITextView`, and `textForWood` is a dictionary. Please help.

Comment: You should not be setting the text to a collection of strings. You need to get a single string from the dictionary. Please refer to this https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITextView/text

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
woodText.text = textForWood["Oak"] as! String
```

You need to assign a String to the `text` of a `UITextView`. The above shows how to extract a String from a Dictionary.

**Addition based on the comments**

I don't think using a dictionary to populate a table view is a good idea. (Remember, dictionaries are not ordered, arrays are.) You should have an array of some kind that informs the table view how many rows it should display and what to display in those rows.

One solution would be an *array of dictionaries* (`[[String : String]]`). You can then populate each cell in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. The dictionary for each row should contain something like

```
["name" : "Oak", "text" : "The text to display in the oak cell..."]
```

Use the standard boilerplate code to dequeue the cell with the text view and then

```
let woodDictionary = textForWood[indexPath.row]!
woodText.text = woodDictionary["text"] as! String
```

It would be much better to use a simple object.

```
struct Wood {
    let name: String
    let text: String
}
```

Comment: And how to do it with multiple keys?

Comment: What do you mean? You want to combine multiple strings?

Comment: I have 12 cells in tableView and and every cell give image and text. This text should be like dictionary, for every cell a certain text.

Comment: In my case I have id and name keys, when id is null then name value is not showing. arrayObject[indexPath.row].source?["name"]

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
var string = ""

for value in textForWood.values.array {
    string = string.stringByAppendingString("\(value), ")
}

woodText.text = string
```

hope this helps.

Comment: just tried this code in the playGround and it worked:

var textForWood = [1:"aa", 2:"bb"]

var string = ""

for value in textForWood.values.array {
    string = string.stringByAppendingString("\(value), ")
}

println("\(string)")

could you please provide some code?

Comment: I have a tableView and I have here an image and a label that leads to the next viewController and there is a text and image that is segued from the first page. In the TextView should stand text on some type of wood. I think it is best with dictionary. var textForWood = ["Ash": "fadsfdasl", "Alder": "kahgfajdfsasgj", "Alder": "fgajhsfaskj"]. woodText is the textView which should provide information about species.